# <audio> hide download controls

Tags: html, css, audio, download

How do you remove the download button from the controls?
I only want the play/pause and volume controls. I don't want people to download the audio files.

This is what I have right now:

```
<audio controls>
 <source src="Test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: *"I don't want people to download the audio files."* But that's what the browser does to play it.

Comment: Not sure about audio, but for html5 video, at least for chrome (thats where the download control appears), you can css set the download not to appear.  - check -webkit-media-controls or something like it for audio.

Comment: Of course, even if you do hide the button, don't assume anyone with basic computer skills won't download it anyway.

Answer (score 10):

Write like this

`<audio controls controlsList="nodownload">`

Answer (score -1):

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    overflow:hidden;
}

audio::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    width: calc(100% + 30px); 
}
//add above css properties in <style></style> it will work definitely.
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.